# what is the difference between removeSpriteFramesFromFile and removeUnusedSpriteFrames?

Tags: caching, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, sprite-sheet

I would really like to know and understand the differences between `removeSpriteFramesFromFile` and `removeUnusedSpriteFrames` and also which cases they are best applied in.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's time for another copypaste from cocos2d header files!

*CCSpriteFrameCache.h*:

```
/** Removes unused sprite frames.
* Sprite Frames that have a retain count of 1 will be deleted.
* It is convinient to call this method after when starting a new Scene.
*/
-(void) removeUnusedSpriteFrames;

/** Removes multiple Sprite Frames from a plist file.
* Sprite Frames stored in this file will be removed.
* It is convinient to call this method when a specific texture needs to be removed.
* @since v0.99.5
*/
- (void) removeSpriteFramesFromFile:(NSString*) plist;
```

Answer (score 0):

removeSpriteFramesFromFile :

Removes multiple Sprite Frames from a plist file. Sprite Frames stored in this file will be removed. It is convenient to call this method when a specific texture needs to be removed.

removeUnusedSpriteFrames :

Removes unused sprite frames. Sprite Frames that have a retain count of 1 will be deleted. It is convenient to call this method after when starting a new Scene.